# Python Module 'Requests' and 'Messages Framework'

Tags: python, django, python-requests

within a Django web app, I am using the aforementioned modules:

- Requests to handle HTTP and
- Messages Framework to collect and render messages

Now, when I am calling the following method of the Messages Framework:

```
messages.add_message(request, messages.INFO, 'Hello world.')
```

it gives me an error saying it requires an HTTPRequest... however, 'Requests' does not match. Any ideas? The full error message is:

add_message() argument must be an HttpRequest object, not 'module'.

The preceding method call for a post is:

```
import requests
<some code...>
response = requests.post(url=dest, data=self.settings, headers=headers)
```

Comment: You are mixing up two different types of request. The `requests` package is a pythonpackage for making HTTP requests. The Django `messages` framework requires a Django [`HttpRequest` object](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest), which is a completely different thing. How exactly are you trying to render messages? Are you doing this from a view?

Answer (score 0):

You should call already defined methods of Django messages framework. You can of course define your own, but for the info messages you can use the predefined info method `messages.info(request, 'Hello world.')`.